# Creating a link for all files in a directory to home

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

I am trying to write a small zsh (bash compatible) script to take each file in ~/.oh-my-zsh/links directory and creates a hard link for it in ~. I am not sure how to do this. Would this be correct?

```
pushd .; 
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh/links; 
ln * ~/*;
popd;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not correct. You should run this:

```
pushd .; 
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh/links; 
ln * ~;
popd;
```

To create a hard link of every file in `~/.oh-my-zsh/links` in `~`.

Comment: +1 or do the work in HOME: `cd && ln .oh-my-zsh/links/* . && cd -`

Comment: Or indeed just `ln ~/.oh-my-zsh/links/* ~`